# Creating a square based on screen width android using constraint layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a view that equals fifty percent of screen width and height should be same as width in a constraint layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        android:id="@+id/cardLayout"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        >
```

However this doesn't seem to be working. I have also tried changing width to `wrap_content`. What needs to be fixed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add start+end (or left+right) constraints to the view so that it knows *what* to be 50% as wide as:

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Answer (score 7):

**Try this code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Screenshot (of the above code):***

[image]

I hope it helps you.